# node js res Cannot GET /

Tags: json, node.js

I launch the Ubuntu on EC2 and running the app on port 80 using nginx. I am trying to exact the data using RESTful get from json "http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=xxx" and render a table. However, Cannot GET / pops out.

The following code is workable:

```
const express = require('express') 

const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.send('HEY!')
}) 
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running on port 3000'))
```

But my code doesnt work.

```
var request = require("request");
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;
var body = new EventEmitter();

request("http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=xxx", function(error, response, data) {
   body.data = data;

   body.emit('update');
});

body.on('update', function () {

   console.log(body.data); 
});
```

Comment: You are trying to access `/api/latest` but your code is looking for requests to `/`

Comment: I edited the question to hide your API key. It's now compromised, you should probably reset it.

Comment: Why are you using an `EventEmitter` to notify when the `request` is finished....why aren't you just processing the data inside the callback? Also, how are both these examples in any way equivalent?